# Why can't I configure a static IP on my CentOS7 system?

Tags: centos, ip

my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 is like this:
[image: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripst/ifcfg-eth0]

And I have issued the command "systemctl restart network".
But when I issued "ifconfig", it shows that the ip on eth0 is 192.168.1.117,but I configured it as static ip 192.168.1.210
Then I issued "ip addr" , I did got ip 192.168.1.210, but the ip 192.168.1.117 also appeared, which I don't want to have at all:
[image: results as "ifconfig" and "ip addr"]

How can I handle it?

Comment: what happens if you do `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0; ip addr` ?

Comment: when I issued "ifdown eth0"，it shows that " Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' " for 4 times.

Comment: and when I issued "ifup eth0", it shows " Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0' " for 4 times ,too

Comment: Then check if the file exist and its permissions first.

Comment: then I issued " ip addr ", it shows that  "inet 192.168.1.117/24" and "192.168.1.210/24" and "inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fee6:d6f3/64"  are all under eth0

Comment: Post the output of `chkconfig --list | grep -i netw`

Comment: I issued "stat ifcfg-eth0" , it shows the access is Access( 0644/-rw-r--r--).

Comment: the output of "chkconfig --list | grep -i netw" is

Comment: Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native systemd configuration. If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'. To see services enabled on particular target use 'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'. network  0:off  1:off  2:on 3:on  4:on  5:on  6:off

Comment: @Julian20151006 try disabling n/w manager with `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`, `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager` and finally run `sudo service network restart` command.

Answer (score 1):

In the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`change `BOOTPROTO` to `none` instead of `static` then restart network using `systemctl restart network`

BOOTPROTO doesn't support `static`, it should be either `none`, `bootp` or `dhcp`

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to NetworkManager service probably being still in use (on CentOS 7).

You need to either disable entirely NetworkManager (recommended on servers) :

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager && systemctl stop NetworkManager && service network restart && chkconfig network on
```

or disable NetworkManager being active on this interface (recommended for desktop), by adding

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

to your `ifcfg-eth0` file.

Comment: yeah, your answer is like @Rahul's answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware to specify your **GATEWAY** correctly, maybe you entered the Subnet IP address.
You need to add a gateway IP that is usually one number higher than it.
So check your IP with an online calculator tool (e.g. [this one](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html)) and find the correct gateway.